# Avoid resize a section while resizing the screen

Tags: css, resize, screen

When a resize the screen, the text get another size.
I wan't to avoid this and show a scroll bar.
Could you help me please  ?

This is my code :

```css
article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section.apropos {
  background-color: white;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: Calibri;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 95px;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  text-align: justify;
  min-width: auto;
  min-height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a> Notre entreprise</a></li>
      <li class="m"><a> Nous connaitre</a></li>
      <li class="m"><a onclick='onLinkClick()'>Nos métiers</a></li>
      <li class="m"><a>Nous contacter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<body>
  <article>

    <section class="apropos">
      <h1> A PROPOS DE NOUS </h1> <br/>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</p>
    </section>

    <section class="NotreMetier" id="NotreMetier">

    </section>

  </article>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 3 times sorry for my english?  If SO tells you to add more "text" you should clarify your problem, not post the same text over and over to fit the code to text ration ...

Comment: simply use a fixed width

Answer (score 0):

Use `width:` and `height:` to make it fixed (400px and 300px in my example).
Optionally use `overflow: scroll;` to give your element scrollbars if the content is bigger than its size.

```css
article {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

section.apropos {
  background-color: white;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: Calibri;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 95px;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a> Notre entreprise</a></li>
      <li class="m"><a> Nous connaitre</a></li>
      <li class="m"><a onclick='onLinkClick()'>Nos métiers</a></li>
      <li class="m"><a>Nous contacter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
  <article>

    <section class="apropos">
      <h1> A PROPOS DE NOUS </h1> <br/>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</p>

      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</p>
    </section>

    <section class="NotreMetier" id="NotreMetier">

    </section>

  </article>
</body>
```